# Is NATO discriminate to take action against any nation?

Tags: armed-conflict, nato

NATO and SEATO are organisations who come forward and fight for civilians rights and injustice. We experienced their activity in Afghanistan, Iraq and Libya. But why NATO is not taking actions against Asad regime in Syria, Israeli forces in Palestine, Burmese military, Chinese government in Xinjiang Uygur region and Indian Army and Pakistani Army in Kashmir region who killed and displaces million of people? 
Is NATO take action only against certain nations, does NATO discriminate to take action?

Answer (score 8):

## NATO is not a humanitarian organization.

[NATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO) is the collective defense organization by various "North Atlantic" countries. The purpose is to defend ([Article 5](https://www.nato.int/nato_static_fl2014/assets/pdf/stock_publications/20120822_nato_treaty_en_light_2009.pdf)) the territory of the NATO members north of the tropic of cancer (Article 6).

There have been few attacks against NATO members. The [Algerian War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algerian_War) was not considered an *external* attack. The [Falklands War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falklands_War) did not count because it was too far south. The 9/11 terror attacks were considered an Article 5 case, which caused Afghanistan and [Iraq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq_War_and_the_War_on_Terror), among other operations in the [war on terror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_on_Terror).

NATO has also acted when several NATO members, individually, decided to act and asked to make use of NATO command facilities. The best example are the various interventions in the breakup of [Yugoslavia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakup_of_Yugoslavia).

So to answer your question, those countries you mention did not attack any NATO member and did not motivate a sufficient number of NATO members to act collectively within the existing NATO structure.

Comment: “those countries you mention did not attack any NATO member”, neither did Libya nor Iraq (Afghanistan is a bit of a stretch but it was at least linked to 9/11 which was experienced as a traumatic attack by the most influence NATO member).

Comment: @Relaxed, Libya would come under the last paragraph. Regarding Iraq, the US administration at the time claimed the terror connection in addition to "Weapons of Mass Distraction". They made it stick. I've added a link.

Comment: Right, but it directly disproves the third one as does the second paragraph. Real attacks were ignored (Falklands), fake attacks were invoked (Iraq) or we dispensed with the pretense entirely. Article 5 provides at best technical legal cover but whether a country genuinely “attacked” a NATO member does not really explain these decisions or answer the question.

Comment: @Relaxed, the Falklands are south of the Tropic of Cancer. They were not "ignored," they were *explicitly excluded* when the treaty was written.

Comment: Sure and the UK didn't request it either but the point still stands.

Comment: @Relaxed, how does the point stand? If I get insurance for my car but not for my bicycle, it is in no way remarkable that the insurance company doesn't cover damage to the bike. The Tropic of Cancer was written into the treaty for very good reasons and everybody did accept that.

Comment: It stands because it was just one example out of three and in all cases the letter of the treaty just served as a thin justification for decisions made on another basis, i.e. the presence of a genuine attack does not explain anything. You zeroed in on article 6 to avoid addressing the overall gist of my comment but it doesn't really matter either way. If you want to discount the Falklands and feel like nitpicking over Iraq, there is still Libya. It's the final nail in the coffin. Or Yugoslavia for that matters. You acknowledged it but failed to draw the obvious conclusion.

Comment: @Relaxed, one can argue that the whole "War on Terror" reasoning is flawed -- 9/11 was almost twenty years ago, leading some people to call it "the longest war" -- but it was the official line of successive US administrations and other NATO countries accepted it.

Comment: One could but that's not the point, the logical conclusion is still that it's all about US policy, not any purported attack against NATO countries. Again, what about Libya? You're very busy starting other discussions or arguing this or that detail but you still haven't addressed that or amended your answer (which I didn't downvote as it's not entirely without merit).

Comment: @Relaxed, I don't share your conclusions. Yugoslavia was very much an *European* concern, and it was one of the first big non-Article-5 missions of NATO. Europe was worried about refugee streams and spillover of the conflict. Note that I gave *that* example in my last paragraph, because it was historically more important than Libya. On the other hand, NATO didn't go to Vietnam or Korea, or the assorted "little wars" the US had in Central America.

Comment: Which conclusions don't you share? You wrote it yourself! Libya hadn't attacked any NATO country, Yougoslavia hadn't attacked any NATO country. It's enough to entirely disprove your third paragraph, NATO operations are not decided by that, it's disingenuous to pretend that the mere fact this or that country did not attack any NATO member explains anything. Why keep it in your answer? Obviously, NATO didn't go to Vietnam and Yougoslavia is a European concern, what does that have to do with anything? I certainly didn't suggest that it wasn't the case!

Comment: @Relaxed, I mean your conclusion that it is all about US policy. The first major departure from defensive deployments in Europe was for the benefit of the European members, not the US.

Comment: Yugoslavia? Fine, if you want to see it that way... But once again, it doesn't matter, we can have all these interesting side discussions, it's still incontrovertible proof that, since the end of the cold war, an attack against a NATO member is not necessary to activate the alliance, even as a pretext. The third paragraph of your answer is therefore flatly wrong, that's not the answer to the question asked by the OP.

Comment: @Relaxed, this point is covered in one out of my four paragraphs. Do you think it should have been higher up?

Comment: No, I think the third paragraph has to go entirely. That point cannot simply be “covered”, as I explained in one of my earlier comments, the fourth paragraph undermines and disproves the third paragraph conclusively. It only makes sense to claim that the lack of attack on a NATO member explains anything if it is a sine qua non and there never was any NATO action without a prior attack. But that's not the case. You cannot simply write the opposite in the next paragraph, it doesn't make it any better.

Comment: Beyond that there could be any number of explanations, too risky, too far away, US policy, not in the interest of European nations, anything you want and probably several of these. But we know it's not about attacks on NATO countries, plain and simple. Even NATO isn't trying to claim that it is anymore! So why bring it up as an explanation? That's the point I have been making all along...

Answer (score 5):

#### Goals of NATO

[NATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO) is the North-Atlantic Treaty Organisation.

Like the previous answers, I would point out that NATO is an association of countries to protect themselves and their interest.

Originally, it was created as a way for the USA to get allies, limit communism extension and defend against the USSR threat.

Thus the actions of NATO may appear inconsistent as far as Human rights are concerned, but that isn't why it's there at all.

#### Specific examples

There are a few examples mentioned in your question or in some comments, and I wanted to clarify some elements:

- **Libya**: NATO did not intervene in Libya as such. But the USA, the UK and France did in their own name. Being the main army forces behind the NATO, we tend to mix them, but no, that was "individual" operations for the most part. NATO as such only participated in the naval blockade.
- **Syria**: actually the same countries backed some groups opposing Al-Assad, but were weary to directly act. Libya is a failed state resulting from the intervention mentioned above. So the Western Powers were trying to find another approach. And then came ISIS. Which meant that their interests shifted slightly. It became more important to eliminate ISIS than to fight against a dictator.
- **Israel**: is a strong ally of the USA, and important cultural and economical partner. They are not a direct threat to NATO members.
- **Burma**: no threat whatsoever to NATO members.
- **China**: no threat whatsoever to NATO members. Plus a direct war against China would have very complex consequences worldwide, so better to avoid being too strong on there.
- **Kashmir**: no threat whatsoever to NATO members. Plus again risk of complex consequences.

Comment: Note that Turkey is also very active in Syria with distinct goals and strategy (and of course no integrated command).

Answer (score 1):

The short and the long of it is that NATO simply follows US policy in these cases. It has no broad mandate to fight against injustice in the world and did not decide to start any of these wars. It lent support after the fact, sometimes reluctantly (very quickly in Libya, with some real fighting in Afghanistan, and only for a limited training mission in Iraq), because the US requested it. But it was not a driving force behind the initial military intervention, operationally or politically.

NATO does require the approval of other members than the US to act and many are weary of risky expeditions so it doesn't automatically follow what the US does. That's why only individual NATO countries (US, UK, France, Turkey, the Netherlands) have been involved in Syria and not under unified command. The more careful members also required some sort of UN sanction before stepping in (not necessarily a full-blown mandate but at least a robust condemnation). Given the political support they enjoy, it's highly unlikely such a resolution would ever get passed against China (it has a veto in the UN security council), Israel, or Syria.

Not to mention the fact it's difficult to believe that anybody would think that a war with India, China, or Pakistan would be a good idea or achieve anything. Politics and foreign support aside, even Israel would be a much more formidable enemy than Afghanistan or Iraq, requiring a strong commitment for a very risky operation.